# How do I use account registration in my app?

Tags: android, eclipse

I'm making an android app game and I want to have my players register a username and password so they could have their own accounts and search players by their username and send play requests like for example Draw Something and Songpop and my question is,

How do I go about this?

This ain't a code question but more of a question on if you could provide me on a video or written guide on this subject.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go have a look at [this](https://github.com/andreipop/Android-Login-App) for a login example app

Read through [this](http://www.stanford.edu/class/ee368/Android/Tutorial-3-Server-Client-Communication-for-Android.pdf) and [this](http://osamashabrez.com/simple-client-server-communication-in-android/) for server communication

On the server end you can use a google server or setup your own server. You can build it in PHP Java or any language you prefer.

Comment: Thank you!This should be what I was looking for.